# How to remove a pending invitation to a Github repo?

Tags: shell, github, github-api

I would like to write a script that uses the GitHub API to remove a pending invitation to a repository. Intended usage would be something like this:

```
./remove_pending_invite.sh <name_of_repo> <their_github_username>
```

I know I can *create* invitations using a sequence of instructions like this:

```bash
# Log in to GitHub
gh auth login --with-token <github_token_here>

# Give the user full access
gh api -XPUT repos/<organization_name>/<name_of_repo>/collaborators/<their_github_username> -f permission=maintain
```

But I don't know how to remove them. My use-case is that I'd like to remove an invitation that's expired (after 7 days) so I can reinvite the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Log in to GitHub
gh auth login --with-token <github_token_here>

# check or install jq (run in Debian, change it by your OS)
which jq || sudo apt-get install -y jq

# Get invitation_id and username
invitationid_usrname=($(gh api repos/<organization_name>/<name_of_repo>/invitations | jq -r '.[] as $i | $i.id, $i.invitee.login'))

for (( i=0; i<${#invitationid_usrname[@]}; i+=2 ));
do
    gh api -XDELETE repos/<organization_name>/<name_of_repo>/invitations/"${invitationid_usrname[$i]}"

    # Give the user full access
    gh api -XPUT repos/<organization_name>/<name_of_repo>/collaborators/"${invitationid_usrname[$i+1]}" -f permission=maintain
done
```

According to `DELETE invitations/` has to be an `invitation_id`, you could get the relationship between `invitation_id` and the username (means `invitee.login`) from the [List repository invitations](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/collaborators/invitations?apiVersion=2022-11-28#list-repository-invitations) API and the `jq` command.

Answer (score 0):

The GitHub API does not provide a direct way to remove a pending invitation.
However, you can work around this by using the GitHub API to list pending invitations for a repository, and then deleting the relevant invitation from this list.

First, use the GitHub API to list the pending invitations for a repository:

```bash
gh api repos/<organization_name>/<name_of_repo>/invitations
```

The response should return a list of pending invitations, with the invitee's GitHub username included in the response.

You can then use the GitHub API to delete the invitation for a particular user:

```bash
gh api -XDELETE repos/<organization_name>/<name_of_repo>/invitations/<their_github_username>
```

This should delete the pending invitation for the specified user from the repository.

Comment: I think `invitations/<their_github_username>` doesn't quite work -- the bit after `invitations/` has to be an `invitation_id` rather than a username, according to the [API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/collaborators/invitations?apiVersion=2022-11-28#delete-a-repository-invitation).